# Apache Tomcat6: Is it possible to auto detect a new version of a war, download and redeploy?

Tags: java, playframework, tomcat6, war, auto-update

I want to produce an "auto updating" application thats running within the tomcat server. Heres a better explanation:

1. A Play Framework 1.2x application war (exploded) running on windows (sadly..)
2. Tomcat check for a new version from http://www.somewebsource.com/app.zip (or whatever extension)
3. Tomcat checks the server every day at 1am and if there is a new version, tomcat will download the file (undeploy the old one?) and autodeploy.

I've searched the web for this, but i couldnt find what "keywords" i should look at.

My application is running on several machines and i want them to be updated without any human interaction. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a cronjob and deploy. With a few line of script code you'll be done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am goind to write a cronjob into tomcat right?

Comment: i am working on windows machine, maybe i should write a batch file and schedule it?

Comment: Yes, that would be equivalent or you could resort to a Perl script.